# Reading xlsx file in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have used this code:

```
library(openxlsx)
fileUrl <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx"
d <- download.file(fileUrl,destfile = "C:/Users/skoma/Desktop/data/dat.xlsx")
data <- read.xlsx("dat.xlsx")
```

This is the error coming up:

> Error in file(con, "r") : invalid 'description' argument In addition:
>   Warning message: In unzip(xlsxFile, exdir = xmlDir) : internal error
>   in 'unz' code

Comment: Try getting rid of `d<-` that has you assigning the actions of `download.file()` to a variable. It may work after than provided you are in the right working directory

Comment: This works for me as it is without any error.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should not passing `download.file` to a variable (`d`).
Then, you want to download that particulary xlsx as a binary file to work. So try this

```
download.file(fileUrl,destfile = "C:/Users/skoma/Desktop/data/dat.xlsx",mode = "wb")
```

where `mode = "wb"` is for binary. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(openxlsx)

fileUrl <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx"

data <- read.xlsx (fileUrl) #read excel file 

write.xlsx(data, "data.xlsx") # write excel file to source
```